# How to fetch order no and selected values when clicked on row button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table structured as below, I want the user `onclick` on view details button to get the value of the order id and the value of the selected option from the `combobox` in an array to use it in ajax to update the database, how can this be done?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tr>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Order No.</th>
    <th>Customer Name</th>
    <th>Order Status</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Jack</td>
    <td><select><option>Delivered</option><option>In Progress</option><option>Cancelled</option></select></td>
    <td><button id="ViewDetails" type="button" value="Ok" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="ViewDetails()">view</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>Adel</td>
    <td><select><option>Delivered</option><option>In Progress</option><option>Cancelled</option></select></td>
    <td><button id="ViewDetails" type="button" value="Ok" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="ViewDetails()">view</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>Aly</td>
    <td><select><option>Delivered</option><option>In Progress</option><option>Cancelled</option></select></td>
    <td><button id="ViewDetails" type="button" value="Ok" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="ViewDetails()">view</button></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: First of all, you have multiple elements with the same id, that is bad practice, use class for this. Second please show us the jquery code you have tried so far.

Comment: First, it's not recommended to use same `id`s on one page

Comment: just pass the order id in ViewDetails [ ViewDetails(order_id) like this] function, and put it there as you put those values in rows.

Comment: @NewPHP try my solution

Comment: Guys, whose answered: none of the `<option>` have `value`. :-(

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay it's valid, if there is no `value`, the value of an option element is the textContent of the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in html:

```
onclick="ViewDetails(this)"
```

js:

```
function ViewDetails(_el){
    var orders_id=$(_el).parent().parent().find("td:first").html();
    alert(orders_id);
    ////////...........
}
```

Comment: type here 'hrml'

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you're looking for. This will get the id and the selected value of the select from the row of witch the pressed button.

```
function ViewDetails(obj) {
  var $obj = $(obj);
  var id, option;

  id = $obj.closest("tr").find("td:eq(0)").text();
  option = $obj.closest("tr").find("td:eq(2) select").val();

  console.log(id + " | " + option)
}
```

Please note that I added `this` to `onclick="ViewDetails()"`, `onclick="ViewDetails(this)"`

**Demo**

```js
function ViewDetails(obj) {
  var $obj = $(obj);
  var id, option;
  
  id = $obj.closest("tr").find("td:eq(0)").text();
  option = $obj.closest("tr").find("td:eq(2) select").val();
  
  console.log(id + " | " + option)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Order No.</th>
        <th>Customer Name</th>
        <th>Order Status</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Jack</td>
        <td><select><option>Delivered</option><option>In Progress</option><option>Cancelled</option></select></td>
        <td><button type="button" value="Ok" class="btn btn-success ViewDetails btn-sm" onclick="ViewDetails(this)">ViewDetails</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Adel</td>
        <td><select><option>Delivered</option><option>In Progress</option><option>Cancelled</option></select></td>
        <td><button type="button" value="Ok" class="btn btn-success ViewDetails btn-sm" onclick="ViewDetails(this)">ViewDetails</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>Aly</td>
        <td><select><option>Delivered</option><option>In Progress</option><option>Cancelled</option></select></td>
        <td><button type="button" value="Ok" class="btn btn-success ViewDetails btn-sm" onclick="ViewDetails(this)">ViewDetails</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a common `class` to each of the `td` containing orderId and a common `class` to each of the `select` element. Then use jquery to find the parent `tr` & use `find` method to to get the values

```js
function viewDetails(elem) {
  // finding parent tr and then the td for orderId
  var orderId = $(elem).parent().parent().find('.odId').text().trim();
  // get selected option from dropdown
  var selectedOption = $(elem).parent().parent().find('.selected').val();
  console.log(orderId, selectedOption)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Order No.</th>
      <th>Customer Name</th>
      <th>Order Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="odId">4</td>
      <td>Jack</td>
      <td><select class='selected'><option>Delivered</option><option>In Progress</option><option>Cancelled</option></select></td>
      <td><button id="ViewDetails_1" type="button" value="Ok" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="viewDetails(this)">Click</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="odId">5</td>
      <td>Adel</td>
      <td><select class='selected'><option>Delivered</option><option>In Progress</option><option>Cancelled</option></select></td>
      <td><button id="ViewDetails_2" type="button" value="Ok" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="viewDetails(this)">Click</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="odId">6</td>
      <td>Aly</td>
      <td><select class='selected'><option>Delivered</option><option>In Progress</option><option>Cancelled</option></select></td>
      <td><button id="ViewDetails_3" type="button" value="Ok" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="viewDetails(this)">Click</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```js
$(document).on('click', '.view_details', function(){
  p = $(this).parents("tr")
  order_id     = p.find("td:first").html()
  select_value = p.find("select").val()
  alert("order_id:"+order_id+"  selected:"+select_value)
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Order No.</th>
            <th>Customer Name</th>
            <th>Order Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Jack</td>
            <td><select><option>Delivered</option><option>In Progress</option><option>Cancelled</option></select></td>
            <td><button id="ViewDetails" type="button" value="Ok" class="btn btn-success btn-sm view_details" >view</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Adel</td>
            <td><select><option>Delivered</option><option>In Progress</option><option>Cancelled</option></select></td>
            <td><button id="ViewDetails" type="button" value="Ok" class="btn btn-success btn-sm view_details" >view</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>Aly</td>
            <td><select><option>Delivered</option><option>In Progress</option><option>Cancelled</option></select></td>
            <td><button id="ViewDetails" type="button" value="Ok" class="btn btn-success btn-sm view_details" >view</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `onclick="ViewDetails()"` to `onclick="ViewDetails(this)"`, this way you'll pass DOM element to your function.

Now your function:

```
function ViewDetails(buttonEl) {
    var row = buttonEl.closest('tr'); // here you'll get your row
    var orderId = row.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].textContent; //order id
    var status = row.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].value; //status
}
```

```js
function ViewDetails(buttonEl) {
    var row = buttonEl.closest('tr'); // here you'll get your row
    var orderId = row.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].textContent; //order id
    var status = row.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].value; //status
    
    console.log(orderId + ' ' + status);
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Order No.</th>
            <th>Customer Name</th>
            <th>Order Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Jack</td>
            <td><select><option>Delivered</option><option>In Progress</option><option>Cancelled</option></select></td>
            <td><button id="ViewDetails" type="button" value="Ok" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="ViewDetails(this)"></button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Adel</td>
            <td><select><option>Delivered</option><option>In Progress</option><option>Cancelled</option></select></td>
            <td><button id="ViewDetails" type="button" value="Ok" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="ViewDetails(this)"></button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>Aly</td>
            <td><select><option>Delivered</option><option>In Progress</option><option>Cancelled</option></select></td>
            <td><button id="ViewDetails" type="button" value="Ok" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="ViewDetails(this)"></button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</tr>
```